# error in image while uploading through ajax

Tags: ajax, codeigniter, file-upload

I am trying to upload image through ajax. at theclient side i am using this code.

```
$(document).on('change','.image_upload',function(){
        readURL(this);
    });
    ///
    function readURL(input) {
            if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = function (e) {


                     save_profile_image(e.target.result);


                }

                reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
            }
            else {
                swal("Sorry - you're browser doesn't support the FileReader API");
            }
        }

        function save_profile_image(image_data){
        var image_code = encodeURIComponent(image_data);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST", 
            url: '<?=base_url()."Dashboard/new_valet_picture";?>',
            data:'valet_image='+image_code,
            success: function(data){
                alert('data');
            }
        });
    }
```

while at the client side i am using codeigniter to save this as image. Image file is created but it won't display because it contains errors.Here is my CI function where this ajax request is being sent.

```
public function new_valet_picture(){
        $user = $this->session->user_id;
        $image_data = $this->input->post('valet_image');
        $name= "valet_".$user.time().".png";

        $profile_image = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $image_data);
        $profile_image = str_replace(' ', '+',$profile_image);
        $unencodedData=base64_decode($profile_image);
        $pth = './uploads/valet_images/'.$name;


        file_put_contents($pth, $unencodedData);

        echo $name;

    }
```

can anybody figure out where i am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

you just wrong to pass parameter in ajax request :

this is your code

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST", 
        url: '<?=base_url()."Dashboard/new_valet_picture";?>',
        data:'valet_image='+image_code,
        success: function(data){
            alert('data');
        }
    });
```

`data:'valet_image='+image_code,` is wrong pass and change that to `data : {vallet_image : image_code}`.

Answer (score 0):

just changing the position of `encodeURIComponent()` helped me

```
///
        function readURL(input) {
                if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
                    var reader = new FileReader();
                    reader.onload = function (e) {


                         save_profile_image(encodeURIComponent(e.target.result));


                    }

                    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
                }
                else {
                    swal("Sorry - you're browser doesn't support the FileReader API");
                }
            }

            function save_profile_image(image_data){
            var image_code = image_data;
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST", 
                url: '<?=base_url()."Dashboard/new_valet_picture";?>',
                data:'valet_image='+image_code,
                success: function(data){
                    alert('data');
                }
            });
        }
```